# Need advice on Entity Manager

Tags: winforms, linq, devforce

I open up a Member form for Add/Editing members. It has its own entity manager and when the Save button is clicked I close the form and go back to a list form.

When the save is processed, I call a routine called CalculateOwing which calculates the members balance. This method is in a separate .cs file cause it can be called from many areas in the application.

Should the CalculateOwing method be in a separate entity manager or in the same entity manager as the member record being processed?

Comment: If you often use CalculateOwing then it should be in the same entity manager.

Answer (score 0):

A response to this question can be seen at http://www.ideablade.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=4686&title=need-advice-on-entity-manager

EDIT:

Including the response here.

"If you want the results of CalculateOwing to be part of the same database transaction, you need to call it before the Save completes and on the same EntityManager that the Save is using."

Comment: Did you see that link and question. both the questions are same. Posting this link wont help him

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure I understand. Both questions are the same and since the link to the forum has a response to the question, I posted the link to reduce duplicate answers. Thus, people clicking on the link will see the answer to this question. Please correct me if I'm wrong but how is this not helping?

Comment: If the problem could have solved their then why he/ she would have posted the same question here?

Comment: I believe it's due to confusion. If you notice, the response on the forum was on April 25th. The poster posted the question on April 24th both here and on the forum. So the poster may have just been trying to find the correct avenue for asking DevForce related questions.

Comment: @DenisK, your answer has been flagged up in the lqp queue.  Please fix it.  Thanks.

Comment: That makes sense. I've revised my post to include the answers from the forum. Please let me know if this is still unhelpful.